# Rails 4 - Pundit Policies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pundit

Im trying to make an app in Rails 4.

I am using Pundit (or trying to).

I have an application policy and an article policy.

Something isn't working. If I set my article policy for show? to be false, I expect not to be able to see the show page for articles.  Instead, I can see the show page - I can't figure out what's wrong.

My application policy is:

```
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def index?
    false
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(:id => record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    false
  end

  def new?
    create?
  end

  def update?
    false
  end

  def edit?
    update?
  end

  def destroy?
    false
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      scope
    end
  end
end
```

My article policy is:

```
class ArticlePolicy < ApplicationPolicy

    def index?
        true
    end

    def show?
        false
        # user.present?
    end

    def create?
        user.present?
                user && user.profile.addresses.exists?(address.id)

    end

    def update?
        user && user.article.exists?(article.id) && user.article.created_at < 15.minutes.ago
        # user.present? #&& user == article.user
    end

    def destroy?
        # user.admin? 
        # user.present?
        user && user.article.exists?(article.id)
    end

    private
        def article
            record
        end

end
```

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

Articles controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_article, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show, :search]


  respond_to :html, :json
# GET /articles
  # GET /articles.json
  def index
    query = params[:query].presence || "*"
    @articles = Article.search(query)
  end

  # def index
  #   if params[:query].present?
  #     @books = Book.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
  #   else
  #     @books = Book.all.page params[:page]
  #   end
  # end

  # GET /articles/1
  # GET /articles/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /articles/new
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    @article.comments.build
  end

  # GET /articles/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /articles
  # POST /articles.json
  def create
    # before_action :authenticate_user!
    # authorize @article
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @article.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@article) }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @article }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @articless = Article.search(params[:search])
    else 
      @articles = Articles.all
    end
  end


  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1
  # PATCH/PUT /articles/1.json
  def update
    # before_action :authenticate_user!
    authorize @article
    respond_to do |format|
    #   if @article.update(article_params)
    #     format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
    #   else
    #     format.html { render :edit }
    #     format.json { render json: @article.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    #   end
    # end
    if @article.update(article_params)
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @article }
      else
        format.json { render json: @article.errors, status:      :unprocessable_entity }
      end
      format.html { render :edit }
    end
  end



  # DELETE /articles/1
  # DELETE /articles/1.json
  def destroy
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    authorize @article
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_article
      @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def article_params
      params[:article].permit(:user_id, :body, :title, :image, :tag_list,
        comment_attributes: [:opinion])
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your articles_controller?

Comment: Put `authorize @article` in your show action.